# Laptop Asus R558UQ not detecting newly installed RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory

My laptop Asus R558UQ (i7 with windows 64 bit) has 8GB ram. I thought of upgrading my ram to 12 gb. So I talked to Asus customer care and they said I can upgrade to up to 12 GB so I check in task manager and bought 2400MHz 4gb ram but it did not detect the ram when i installed it after that I also bought 2133Mhz 4GB ram but it is also not detecting this ram.

The RAM is of Crucial Brand.

[image]

AS you can see in the screenshot below that it is telling that I have 8 gb 2400Mhz RAM. But I am not able to understand why it is not detecting the ram.

Also I cleaned the RAM pin slot as well as I thought maybe because of dust it is not able to detect it, but that is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Did you have 1x 8GB stick, or 2x 4GB sticks in previously? Have you tried swapping the ram around to see if it makes a difference? You could try pulling the 8GB and putting only the 4GB in the slot where the 8GB was and see if it detects the single stick.

Comment: According to the screenshot you provide, you have a single 8 GB module installed, you have no other module installed.

Comment: @Ramhound yes you are right. I tried to add add another 4 gb in other slot but it was not detecting it. But it Seems that the connection was loose so I tried push the ram further and it work.